# NetBeans: Force external class to be statically compiled into JAR?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have a NetBeans project that relies on one specific Java class in another project.  Right now, when NetBeans compiles the project, it only adds a reference to the other Java class, which leads to a NoClassDefFoundError since the external class isn't in the JAR.

How can I force NetBeans to compile that external file into the JAR when it builds, short of copying and pasting it over?

Comment: It is not.  They're vanilla NetBeans Java projects.

Comment: Vanilla means it uses NetBeans' built-in Ant-based build mechanisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that you are trying to create what it commonly known as a "fat JAR file"; i.e. a JAR file that contains all required classes for your application.

Try the recipe in [this forum posting](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/showpost.php?p=3189462&postcount=5).

Another alternative might be to add something like the following to your Ant `buld.xml` file.

```
<target name="-post-jar">
   <jar update="true" destfile="${dist.jar}">
     <zipfileset src="${javac.classpath}"/>
   </jar>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's Maven based, simply use the ant task to copy the class to your target/classes in the appropriate phase (I guess compile-sources or such - something before `test`).

If it's Ant based, you'd have to hack NetBeans' ant build scripts, which are extensible per-project.

BTW, the standard way is to make the "another project" a dependency of your project. That class might need another classes from that project... and so on.

I might also recommend JDGUI to decompile that project and to cherry-pick the classes you need.  http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui